# SEO, htaccess and div id's

Tags: jquery, html, .htaccess

Curious as to the practice of using .htaccess to eliminate #hashtags in a div id, I have large amount of content and don't want endless html files, instead I want to call them from a database. I don't want to reload the page, just the section where content should be.

For example:
`mysite.com/one/#name-is-here` to `mysite.com/one/name-is-here`

Does this make it harder tp optimise on google? if I am to submit this page to sitemap will google recognise that address as a page?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about search engine optimization which is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

It is curious indeed, because the rules or actions taken by anything in the htaccess file is unable to handle URL fragments. Anything starting from the `#` is completely on the client's end. When the browser loads:

```
http://mysite.com/one/#name-is-here
```

the only thing that is sent to the web server is: `/one/`, the `#name-is-here` is never sent to the server and nothing in the htaccess file even knows of its existence.

Fragments are used by the browser to tell it how to deal with its content, either by paging to a certain anchor on the page or something that javascript can pass back and forth. I don't think google cares about URL fragments but I may be wrong. A URL like `mysite.com/one/#name-is-here` shouldn't be treated any differently than `mysite.com/one/`.

The way to get rid of these hashtags is to remove them from your content. You can then replace the fragments with the pathnames that you suggested. How that pathname gets handled is entirely dependent on you and the script that generates the content from the database.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond and the information. Would recommend using a javascript rewrite method to eliminate the hashtag? Using this would in turn give exact URL path like  `mysite.com/one/name-is-here` but would search engines pick up on this?